# From code: Change ScrollViewer's scrollbars'-style to touch

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

Touch:

[image]

Mouse:

[image]

How do I tell the `ScrollViewer` to start using the touch-style scrollbar from code?

Here's an example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill">
            <Image.Source>
                <BitmapImage x:Name="bitmapImage1" UriSource="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png"></BitmapImage>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer1 = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
    bool SE;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        dispatcherTimer1.Tick += DispatcherTimer1_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer1.Start();
    }

    private void DispatcherTimer1_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (SE = !SE) bitmapImage1.UriSource = new Uri("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-icon.png");
        else bitmapImage1.UriSource = new Uri("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png");
        scrollViewer1.ChangeView(SE ? 1 : 0, SE ? 1 : 0, null);
    }
}
```

If you run this (at least on a touch enabled PC) the scrollbars will initially be touch. And if you then move the cursor over it with the mouse, it will change to mouse. and if you then touch it (after the scrollbars have been hidden) it will return to touch.

I want to tell it programmatically to change from one to the other. How can that be done? If the only way is by editing the template - how can that be done *without* hard coding [the template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299151.aspx) ? Just fixing the detail that needs fixing. To be clear: I want to be able to call a method that will change from one to the other: `void ChangeTo(bool mouse) { ... }`. (Though, failing that, just forcing the ScrollViewer to always be in one mode, would be somewhat of a workaround.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within default template there are 3 VisualStates defined:
NoIndicator,
TouchIndicator and
MouseIndicator

Style of scroller thumb looks different depending on which state is currently set.
To change controls state you can call

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(scrollViewer1, "TouchIndicator");
```

but you would need to manually take care of all events and actions when this state may change.

But if you want to have always TouchIndicator visible then better solution in my opinion would be to implement CustomVisualStateManager, for example:

```
public class MyVisualStateManager : VisualStateManager
{
    protected override bool GoToStateCore(Control control, FrameworkElement templateRoot, 
        System.String stateName, VisualStateGroup group, VisualState state, System.Boolean useTransitions)
    {
        switch (stateName)
        {
            case "NoIndicator":
            case "TouchIndicator":
            case "MouseIndicator":
                base.GoToStateCore(control, templateRoot, "TouchIndicator", group, state, useTransitions);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you need to copy the template from MSDN, set it to your ScrollViewer and put MyVisualStateManager within it:

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollViewer" x:Key="ScrollStyle">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                            <local:MyVisualStateManager/>
                        </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollingIndicatorStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="MouseIndicator" To="NoIndicator">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                (... blabla ...)
</Style>
```

style set:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer1"  Style="{StaticResource ScrollStyle}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

Now whenever your ScrollViewer state needs to be changed, you are ignoring what exact state it wants, setting TouchIndicator instead.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be it. Though I didn't understand what you meant by `but you would need to manually take care of all events and actions when this state may change.`, since I'm not unsubscribing from any events, why should anything change (except for the state, of course)?

Comment: For example change state of ScrollViewer is triggered every time mouse pointer enters and exits ScrollViewer (and even if you move mouse inside as far as I remember). So if you set it with VisualStateManager.GoToState(something) it will be changed and set to IndicatorMouse if any mouse pointer would enter it. Seems like arguing with the system about which state should be set (my my my! ;) Using CustomiVisualStateManager is better is a way you are cutting of the system the way you are the one to decide when and which state should be set.

Comment: I think @maxp 's solution is the correct one , for 2020. I've tested it and runs perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Windows has two scroller visualizations, which are based on the user's input mode: **scroll indicators** when using touch or gamepad; and interactive **scroll bars** for other input devices including mouse, keyboard, and pen.

[image]

And in [Guidelines for panning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/guidelines-for-panning),  it is declared that

> There are two panning display modes based on the input device detected:
>
> - Panning indicators for touch.
> - Scroll bars for other input devices, including mouse, touchpad, keyboard, and stylus.
>
> **Note** Panning indicators are only visible when the touch contact is within the pannable region. Similarly, the scroll bar is only visible when the mouse cursor, pen/stylus cursor, or keyboard focus is within the scrollable region.
>
> **Panning indicators** Panning indicators are similar to the scroll box in a scroll bar. They indicate the proportion of displayed content to total pannable area and the relative position of the displayed content in the pannable area.
>
> **Note** Unlike standard scroll bars, panning indicators are purely informative. They are not exposed to input devices and cannot be manipulated in any way.

So the display mode is based on user's input mode, we can't programmatically change it from one to the other. What we can do is editing [ScrollViewer's template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299151) so that ScrollViewer will only use one visualization UI.

In the default style, we can find `ScrollViewer` has three  [VisualState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate)s: **NoIndicator**, **TouchIndicator** and **MouseIndicator**, which are used to control the display mode. We can change **TouchIndicator** or **MouseIndicator** visual state to make the `ScrollViewer` always in one display mode.

For example, we can replace the `Storyboard` under "TouchIndicator" `VisualState` with the `Storyboard` under "MouseIndicator" `VisualState` to make the `ScrollViewer` always in scroll bar mode like:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MouseIndicatorTemplate" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollingIndicatorStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition From="MouseIndicator" To="NoIndicator">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0:0:3" TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualTransition>
                    <VisualTransition From="TouchIndicator" To="NoIndicator">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualTransition>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="NoIndicator">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="TouchIndicator">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>MouseIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>MouseIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseIndicator">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>MouseIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>MouseIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
            <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       IsTabStop="False"
                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                       Orientation="Vertical"
                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                       Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" />
            <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       IsTabStop="False"
                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                       Orientation="Horizontal"
                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                       Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" />
            <Border x:Name="ScrollBarSeparator"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Background="{ThemeResource ScrollViewerScrollBarSeparatorBackground}" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And vice versa.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TouchIndicatorTemplate" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollingIndicatorStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition From="MouseIndicator" To="NoIndicator">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation BeginTime="0:0:3" TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualTransition>
                    <VisualTransition From="TouchIndicator" To="NoIndicator">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <ScrollingIndicatorMode>None</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualTransition>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="NoIndicator">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="TouchIndicator">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>TouchIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>TouchIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseIndicator">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ScrollBarSeparator" />
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>TouchIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IndicatorMode" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <ScrollingIndicatorMode>TouchIndicator</ScrollingIndicatorMode>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
            <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       IsTabStop="False"
                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                       Orientation="Vertical"
                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                       Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" />
            <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       IsTabStop="False"
                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                       Orientation="Horizontal"
                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                       Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" />
            <Border x:Name="ScrollBarSeparator"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Background="{ThemeResource ScrollViewerScrollBarSeparatorBackground}" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Once we have these two templates, we can use [ScrollViewer.Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.template) property to change the display mode from one to the other like following ( "MouseIndicatorTemplate" and "TouchIndicatorTemplate" are placed in `Page.Resources`):

```
void ChangeTo(bool mouse)
{
    if (mouse)
    {
        scrollViewer1.Template = (ControlTemplate)Resources["MouseIndicatorTemplate"];
    }
    else
    {
        scrollViewer1.Template = (ControlTemplate)Resources["TouchIndicatorTemplate"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to restore the simple scrollbar behavior one might expect from a WPF app (removing the touch indicator altogether). The example given by @Jay Zuo didn't work, so I created my own. The templates can be viewed at the following repository:

https://github.com/jsymon/UWP-Classic-ScrollBar-Template

[image]